# Regular expression for decimal numbers with limiting character size

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to frame regular expression that matches the following criteria. Can you please suggest me a solution.

I tried with : `^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`

It is working as expected but now i want to add a pattern to limit the character size up to 10(max) including period('.') in the text box.

Acceptance Criteria Values (When Char length is 6) :
`.5`, `0.5`, `1.2`, `33.33`, `123.45`

Rejection Criteria Values (When Char length is 6) :
`.5.0`, `-0.5`, `2.333`, `122.456`, `1234.56` (rejected because the length is 7 including dot ('.')

Comment: Post your current solution and what you get for it first.

Comment: `.` need to be escaped to match as decimal literal.

Comment: is this a winforms  or web or UWP application? can you set a [`MaxLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.maxlength(v=vs.110).aspx) property?

Comment: You may just impose the restriction with a lookahead: `^(?=.{1,10})[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$`.

Comment: This is I'm trying in C# Xamarin. I would like to give some acceptance criteria.

Acceptance Criteria(When Char length is 6): .2, 0.2, 1.2,9.45, 234.45 (No Negative values allowed)
Rejection Criteria (When Char length is 6): 1234.12

Comment: @NaveenBathina: When you have to add something to question, edit the original question and not in comment.

Comment: If you need to support `.5` like values, you may use `^(?=.{1,10})[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+$`. If it works for you, I will post

Comment: @noob : Thanks noob I have edited my question and please provide regular expression for my acceptance and rejection criteria..

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew your pattern is allowing .55555 also which is not needed for me. can you check my edited question for better understanding.

Comment: Now, you say max is 6? No idea what you need. Please formulate you requirements more verbally.

Comment: Know that Regular Expressions are not programming language. You can implement if condition though. But if you check for negative values and length of string prior to matching a patter using programming language it will facilitate you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with a positive look-ahead. First check the condition then match:

```
string pattern = @"(?x)  (?=^.{1,10}$ ) (^ \d+ (\.\d{1,2})? $) | (^\.\d{1,2}$)";
```

`(?=^.{1,10}$ )` is the look-ahead, matches a string from 1 to 10 inclusive, then you match :
`(^ \d+ (\.\d{1,2})? $)` matches any digit followed by . and 1 or 2 other digits

| or

`(^\.\d{1,2}$)`  matches . followed by 1 or 2 digits

Answer (score 1):

Thanks,

I got answer like splitting into two regular expressions. One for numeric validation and another for length validation. If both conditions match then it is said as accepted.

Thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Naveen